# Database table for storage of one value?

Tags: php, sql

Hopefully this question is not to broad, but I am writing a plugin for creating and managing site Backups as well as restoring site backups. All of the config variables are stored in an array, but one needs to be stored/editable by the user in the UI.

*Does it make sense to make a database table with only one column and row to store this variables value?* Or should I write it to a file? In any case the plugin will always require database access so its not like I'd be writing extra functionality for that.

Comment: You could use a file. Or better yet, use [PHP dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: That seems like a lot of additional overhead for something so simple?

Comment: This way, you can easily separate configuration from code. And it allows you to have hassle free development, staging and production configuration.

Comment: should you nail a nail with a Truck or a hammer, of-course the hammer :)

Comment: @niceman I like the analogy! ;)